# currentState.validate() Causing Flutter App to Crash

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter app and I have an issue when I navigate to this particular screen.  The simulator crashes and displays a message saying:

NoSuchMethodError: The method 'validate' was called on null
Receiver: null
Tried calling: validate()

I don't understand why the validate() method is being called even though it is contained within the _submit function which is only called when a button within the screen is pressed.  When I remove the function call from onPressed: the app works.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:service_request/services/auth_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SignupForm extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'signup_screen';

  @override
  _SignupFormState createState() => _SignupFormState();
}

class _SignupFormState extends State<SignupForm> {
  final _signUpFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _name, _email, _password;

  _submit() {
    if (_signUpFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _signUpFormKey.currentState.save();
      // Logging in the user w/ Firebase
      AuthService.signUpUser(context, _name, _email, _password);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sign Up'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _signUpFormKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Name',
                      ),
                      validator: (input) => input.trim().isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter a valid name'
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (input) => _name = input,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                          ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Email Address',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (input) => input.length < 6
                          ? 'Must be at least 6 characters'
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          width: 350.0,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: Text(
                              'Sign Up',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          width: 350.0,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: _submit(),
                            child: Text(
                              'Back to Log In',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_submit()` means execute this function. you have to remove `()` 
you can copy paste run full code below

code snippet

```
FlatButton(
                            onPressed: _submit,
                            child: Text(
                              'Back to Log In',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SignupForm extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'signup_screen';

  @override
  _SignupFormState createState() => _SignupFormState();
}

class _SignupFormState extends State<SignupForm> {
  final _signUpFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _name, _email, _password;

  _submit() {
    if (_signUpFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _signUpFormKey.currentState.save();
      // Logging in the user w/ Firebase
      //AuthService.signUpUser(context, _name, _email, _password);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sign Up'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _signUpFormKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Name',
                      ),
                      validator: (input) => input.trim().isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter a valid name'
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (input) => _name = input,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                          ? 'Please enter a valid email'
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Email Address',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (input) => input.length < 6
                          ? 'Must be at least 6 characters'
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          width: 350.0,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: Text(
                              'Sign Up',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          width: 350.0,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: _submit,
                            child: Text(
                              'Back to Log In',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SignupForm(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You’re calling a method instead of setting a callback. The compiler would normally pick this up, but your method is not typed. Untyped methods in Dart return a dynamic object, which could be a function, which is why you’re allowed to call it from your widget. It should be fixed by either changig it to `onPressed: _submit` or `onPressed: () => _submit()` as these are functions and not method calls.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple, wasted way too much time trying to figure it out.  Thank you for responding, I really appreciate it.